# Adding `www` causing it to have index.php

Tags: craft3, htaccess

I am trying to get pretty urls

In my general.php file I have

```
'omitScriptNameInUrls' => true,
```

which works fine and removes the index.php

**BUT**

When I try to force a `www` in the htaccess the index.php comes back and I can't seem to remove this.

This is what I have in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you certain that you're using Craft 3? Otherwise we should remove the [tag:craft3] tag. (I'm not sure it's relevant anyway.)

Comment: yeah I am using the latest craft

Answer (score 3):

Your `.htaccess` is basically saying "Redirect example.com to www.example.com".

OK, that's cool. so you want to add `www` to any request that a comes in. I'm guessing you put this *after* Craft's code?

This actually needs to come *before* you send the request to Craft.

So, your example should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  #Make sure the rewrite engine is on
  RewriteEngine On

  # Redirect non-www requests to www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC] 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

  # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```